# AC blowing hot air

Tags: wiring, hvac, thermostat

I have been remodeling a small building for the last 6 months or so. We had power disconnected to this building since April. We just barely got the power back on, and after some work were able to get the AC unit back on. Yeah!

We turned on the AC for the first time today. The temperature outside was about 80 F, inside about 78F. I set the thermostat to 76F, just to make sure it was working. About an hour later, the inside of the place was 90F. I did also note that the outside condenser was blowing what felt like cold air to me, although it might have been outdoor temperature air.

In theory, the HVAC system was not touch at all for the last 6 months, aside from having the power reconnected. I did also replace the thermostat right before the power went off. Everything seemed to be working fine, but it is entirely possible that I never properly tested the AC when I changed the thermostat, as it happened in April and AC wasn't really needed then.

I suspect my problem is in my wiring of the thermostat. Based on the cool air from the condenser and how quickly the unit heated up, I suspect it was somehow in heat pump mode, but I could be wrong there. I have included pictures of the wiring, along with an image from the blower of the thermostat, which has a nice color code of what each of the wires should be.

[image]
[image]

The thermostat is a Honeywell Wi-Fi 7-Day Programmable Thermostat (RTH6580WF), bought 5 years ago. It worked at a previous location just fine.

Sadly I don't have pictures of the wiring before I removed the old thermostat. I can gladly get more pictures if required.

The previous setup for the thermostat was with a normal AC, gas heater. The new one is a heat pump system.

Comment: Disconnect the W2 and W, to turn off heating. Then figure out what is what

Comment: What I did for the short term was to turn the system off period to stop heating up the place further. Figuring out what is what might be a solution, although I think I'm on to another solution (Ask the question finally and one figures out the answer...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to look at the settings. The wires are used differently depending on if it is a heat pump or gas, etc. There is a setting that needs to be configured correctly to do so. I managed to download a copy of the manual from [this site](https://www.wink.com/downloads/help/honeywell-thermostat-rth6580wf/user-guide.pdf) by Googling "Honeywell installer manual RTH6580WF".

The key is on page 48. Enter the setup mode by pressing the up arrow and the fan button at the same time for 3 seconds. When doing so, make sure Option 1 is set correctly. I had it set to 8 "Heat/Cool multiple stages", the correct is 1 "Heat Pump", or more likely 5 "Heat pump: Heat pump with backup or auxiliary heating", with the aux heating being electric. Mode 1 will heat, 5 will allow for the backup heat if the temperature gets too low.